# Open Android app from Chrome browser

Tags: android, url, browser

I have been trying to make an app which opens automatically when a specific url is entered in the browser. To do so I've been using and intent filter within my manifest like so:

```
<intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="maltapark.com"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
</intent-filter>
```

This works fine but only in my default web browser. When I use chrome the app doesn't open.
I have also tried using firefox and it only opens my app with some but not all URLs such as abc://test.

Is there a way to get my app to open irrespective of the browser or URL being used please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `intent` scheme, as [explained here](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents). The "Android Browser" may or may not support this, and you might have to rely on iframes. What FireFox does is anyone's guess, but personally I don't believe FireFox is a serious contender on the Android platform.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

use this in manifest

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="maltapark.com"
                android:path="/"
                android:scheme="TESTSCHEME" />
        </intent-filter>
```

and use this in tag a

```
"intent://maltapark.com/#Intent;scheme=TESTSCHEME;package=com.YOURPACKAGENAME.www;end"
```

this is worked for me

Answer (score -1):

What are the URL's you are trying to intercept with your app? You mentioned it doesn't work with something like abc://test, which is correct.

Your intent filter is declaring it wants to intercept urls that match http://maltapark.com.

If the url doesn't match that, it won't open.

Answer (score -1):

try putting in the '*' wildcard in the andriod:scheme and maybe andriod:host attribute (if that is what you needed).